# Como cambiar el título del action bar en un Fragment

Tags: android

Buen día estimados, estoy teniendo problemas con los action bar, no cambian su titulo, Tengo un fragment de un Login quemado, cuando inicio sesión me envia al otro fragmant, pero no me cambia el titulo del action bar continua con el nombre de Iniciar Sesion, intente usar el getActivity.setTittle pero no me funciona, de antemano les quedo agradecido.

```
String correo = email.getText().toString();
                String contra = password.getText().toString();
                boolean flag = false;

                if(correo.equals("juan.perez@gmail.com") && contra.equals("12345"))
                    flag= true;

                 if(flag){
                     Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     ServiciosFragment fragment = new ServiciosFragment();
                     FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                     ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,  fragment, "fragment_meters");
                     ft.addToBackStack(null);
                     ft.commit();

                 }else {
                     Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Correo o Contraseña Invalidos...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa el método [setTitle(CharSequence title)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setTitle(int)) del [ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)

> [setTitle(CharSequence title)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setTitle(int)) : Establece el título de la barra
>   de acción (ActionBar).

obten la instancia y define un titulo:

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Hola StackOverflow en Español");
```

**En tu caso me parece que deseas cambiar el texto desde tu `Fragment`**, puedes obtener la referencia mediante  `getActivity().getActionBar()` y de esta forma asignar el titulo:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Hola StackOverflow en Español");
```

si no puedes obtener la referencia del `ActionBar` desde el `Fragment`, en este caso debes realizar casting a `(AppCompatActivity)` :

```
 ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hola StackOverflow en Español");
```

debes obtener como resultado el cambio del titulo en tu `ActionBar`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero me sigue saliendo error, 
                 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: getSupportActionBar(); no me reconoce, me sale rojo

Comment: getSupportActionBar() es si usas la library de soporte pero mejor lo elimino de mi respuesta!, usa solo : getActionBar()

Comment: ServiciosFragment fragment = new ServiciosFragment();
                   ................
                     ft.commit();
                     getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Servicios");

pero me sigue saliendo error:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: De que clase extiende tu Activity  en la cual contienes el código que muestras?

Comment: No es una Actitivy, es desde un Fragment que contiene un diseño de Login a lo que inicio sesion me lleva al otro Fragment pero no me cambia el titulo del Action bar

Comment: Ok entonces realiza un "casting" : ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Servicios"); edite mi respuesta @TonyOrmaza No olvides marcar las respuestas que ayuden a solucionar la problematica expuesta en la pregunta, revisa [tour], saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amigo, me funciono...   :D
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar `getActivity()` usa `getActionBar()`

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Test");
```

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero sigue sin funcionar