# ¿Cómo enlazar el título de un Fragment a una string en Android Studio?

Tags: android, string, android-fragment

Estoy tratando de colocar como título de los fragments de mi app, una string del archivo string.xml del proyecto. Creí que sería tan sencillo como llamar a la string, pero no me permite, ¿ideas de como lograrlo? Lo apreciaría mucho, gracias.

Lo que quiero añadir está como comentario "//"

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            int unread = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Chat chat =  snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && !chat.isIsseen()) {
                    unread++;
                }
            }

            if (unread == 0) {
                viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ChatsFragment(), "Chats");
            }
            else {
                viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ChatsFragment(), "("+unread+") Chats");
            }

            viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new UsersFragment(), "Users");  //setTitle(R.string.fragment_users_title)
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ProfileFragment(), "Profile");  //setTitle(R.string.fragment_profile_title)

            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Al llamar el método addFragment() almacenas los nombre en una lista dependiendo de la posición de cada Fragment:

```
viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new UsersFragment(), "Users");
viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ProfileFragment(), "Profile");
```

Debes obtener el nombre y puedes realizar algo similar a lo que se realiza en esta pregunta, configurando el titulo desde el Fragment:

[Como cambiar el título del action bar en un Fragment](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329247/como-cambiar-el-t%c3%adtulo-del-action-bar/329253#329253)

en tu caso

Comment: no me funciona la implentacion de ese ejemplo, tienes algun otro link de donde pueda intentar? lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Puedes enviar enviar al constructor el nombre new UsersFragment("Users") o dentro de cada fragmento cambiar el nombre del actionbar